# how to show a message in popup at a page when a user come to that page but the condition is we have to use Featherlight popup no Colorbox or etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Please visit at this url, there is a 'default' button when you click on this url a popup will appear.
I want the same but when i don't want to fire any user event this popup will appear onload

http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the popup on page load then just add some JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup").click();
});
```

give the id or class name of your tag where is popup exit instead of `popup` object.

Comment: i don't want to use any user side event